# IntegrityError - Column cannot be null DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

Everything works good in views and templates. When Ive made serializer and then APIVIew something wrong happend. GET method is ok, but POST is not. When I try to add food I get IntegrityError like this: (but in admin panel and GUI you can add food normally so its not problem with model the problem must be with serializer)

> IntegrityError at /food_list_serializer/
>
> Column 'kcal' cannot be null

MODEL look like this:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=124)
    kcal = models.FloatField()
    proteins = models.FloatField()
    carbs = models.FloatField()
    fats = models.FloatField()
    grams = models.FloatField(default=100, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
```

SERIALIZER:

```
class FoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = '__all__'
```

VIEWS:

```
class FoodListSerializer(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        food = Food.objects.all()
        serializer = FoodSerializer(food, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        food_create = Food.objects.create()
        serializer = FoodSerializer(food_create, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

[POST request in DJANGO rest framework looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyqyw.png)

Comment: What does the post request look like? is kcal being passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
food_create = Food.objects.create()
```

You are telling Django to create and save a `Food` object in database with zero arguments, before actually parse the `POST` data. Inside the `Food` model you have a lot of fields that are required (one of which is `kcal` field). Remove this line, since `FoodSerializer` will be "filled" with `request.data` (`POST`) values.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But Im pretty sure that Ive got the same solution in other project and it works. But I will try to do it anyway. Thanks once again!

Comment: It must be it! You are creating and saving to db an object without any parameters passed (and `Food` fields do not have any `default` values specified).